# UWP: Refresh MapElementsLayer

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I have a MapLayer defined on my MapControl using the following:

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name=“MyMap”
[…]
Layers=“{x:Bind ViewModel.Layers}”>
```

I defined a MapElementsLayer and added it to my MapLayer.

I now programmatically create elements and add them to my MapElementsLayer. My issue is that when I add new elements, or delete the elements that are already there, they do not draw/clear on the map. The only way I have been able to get them to update, is to delete the map layer, and re-add it. This process is resource intensive and halts the UI thread for a number of seconds each time.

Is there anyway to update the contents of a MapLayer/MapElementsLayer and trigger a redraw? I have searched the documentation and cannot find a way to trigger a redraw.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Please try to use [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) to replace List.

Comment: Thank you!! I replaced list with ObservableCollection and made the view model inherit INotifyPropertyChanged and its now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive from your description, you may use `List` to insert `Layers`, if you want to update the Layers by removing the source data, please use use [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) to replace List that could represent a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed. For more please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#working-with-layers).

```
public ObservableCollection<MapLayer> LandmarkLayer
    { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MapLayer>();
```